# What does it mean to declare a function as a pointer in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to wrap my head around what it means to delcare a function as a pointer. I remember it briefly being mentioned in one of my textbooks that you could do it but not to a great deal of detail on how to or what it does. For example:

```
double *functionName(double *variableOne, double variableTwo){
}
```

Specifically:

- What does this even mean? A pointer points to an address, but a function isn't a variable, so I am having trouble understanding the purpose and application of such a declaration.
- What kind of return type would this have? Would it just return a pointer?
- How would you call this? My best guess would be:

```
double inputVariableOne,inputVariableTwo;
double *variableName = functionName(&inputVariableOne,inputVariableTwo); //assuming input variables had values
```

I tried searching online for an answer, but all of the ones I found related to C++. I also borrowed another book from the local library but couldn't find anything in there either. Maybe I am wording my question wrong.

Comment: Perhaps, reading `double *functionName()` as `double* functionName()`, will make it clear. Function returns an address of a `double` variable. Yes, your invocation of function call is correct.

Comment: FYI: `double *fx(args);` is [the declaration of] a function that returns a pointer; `double (*fx)(args);` is [the declaration of] a pointer to a function.

Comment: EngineerTaiga, Perhaps you are thinking of: `return_type (*functionPointer)();` declares `functionPointer` as a pointer to a function.  That function returns a `return_type` and its calling signature is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the function returns a pointer to a double. This is how you would return a raw array for example.

The way you have called the function is correct.